# My iptables redirection rule does not effect

Tags: linux, networking, router, ssh, iptables

Here is my network topology, 101.101.101.101 and 202.202.202.202 are global IP while 10.0.1.1 and 10.0.1.251 are local IP. Host B is my computer. [image]

I can SSH to the router and then SSH to Host A on the router. Now I want to SSH to A directly by setting iptables on the router, such as: forwarding all the packets with destination host 101.101.101.101 and port 25122 to 10.0.1.251:22.

The follow three instructions are applied:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 101.101.101.101 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25122 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.1.251:22
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o br-lan -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.1.1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0.2 -j SNAT --to-source 101.101.101.101
```

After executed, they are shown in the list of  `iptables -t nat  -v -n -L`. The route rules on the router like this:

```
#route -n
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         101.101.101.254 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0.2
10.0.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br-lan
```

After all these are done, however, I still can't SSH to A by "ssh 101.101.101.101 25122" on B. It just fails with:

```
Could not connect to '101.101.101.101' (port 25122): Connection failed.
```

1. The situation is, the tcpdump tools cann't be installed on the router to see the packects status there. But I can run tcpdump on Host A and confirm that no packet is forward from the router.
2. On the router,

   ```
   #cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
   1
   ```

which shows the forward is enabled.

3. By running `iptables -t nat  -v -n -L` each time after I did ssh on B, I can see the packets of PREROUTING of the router changes.

   ```
   Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 39526 packets, 3345K bytes)
   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   14   712 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            115.156.132.118     tcp dpt:25122 to:10.0.1.251:22
   ```

The first number (14) increases each time I run the ssh to port 25122 on the host B. This indicates that the packets arrived at the router but not forwarded?

4. I run `iptables -v -n -L` and find that the default policy of FORWARD chain is DROP while the INPUT and OUTPUT chain are ACCEPT. I then set the FORWARD chain to accept by using `iptables --policy FORWARD ACCEPT`. However, the ssh still fails as above.

So, here I am. Can this be a problem of the hard limit of the router, or wrong settings of the iptables. If it is the latter, how should I set it to achieve my goal?

Thank you very much for any clues.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to simplify things first and try guidance you are quite sure about. And common sense. I can sympathise with `iptables` questions a lot as I once spent 3 days working on that and concepts quickly get fuzzy, unless you get a setup which is working right.

For ssh to work you only need this if default policy is ACCEPT:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 101.101.101.101 -p tcp --dport 25122 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.1.251:22
```

On server rules however I would prefer to distinguish objects not by ip address but by interface name. Say the outside interface is `eth4` and the interface that faces your network is `eth1` then this should work and be sufficient:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth4 --dport 25122 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.1.251:22
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth4 -o eth1 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth4 -p tcp -j ACCEPT
```

The last 2 rules are needed in case FORWARD chain policy is something else than ACCEPT.

You can list interfaces like so: `ip addr list`.

And before deciding if changes do not work remember to restore firewall to the default state you want it to be in just before applying the critical changes. For example flush chains and restart iptable service. And you already enabled forwarding at the kernel.

Best of luck!

Comment: First thank you for the the detail answer. But I think the two SNAT rules are also necessary because I must make sure that the packets forwarded to Host B will get back from the router: this is only true if the Host B has set the router as its default gate way, while B is in local network. Any way, I will try your advice days  later.

Comment: No, not so as host B thinks that it is doing SSH with the router. Host B does not need to know the packets are forwarded between router and A